# Can someone help me with a Python command for ctrl + c

Tags: python, secure-crt

I am running a python script on Secure CRT to capture certain data logs. My logs can be stopped by pressing ctrl+c physically on the keyboard. So far I have used the following but to no avail. Can someone tell me how to send ctrl+c as a command to secure CRT ?

1. `tab.Screen.Send("kill -2\n")`
2. ```py
   import os
   import signal
   os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGINT)
   ```

Comment: Note that Control-C causes the terminal to send SIGINT to every process in the current process *group*, not just the current process as in your second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. If anyone faces a similar issue in the future -

```
    tab.Screen.Send("\003")
```

OR

```
    crt.Screen.Send("\003")
```